# Cortana App Open a Webpage

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, cortana

I need to write an Cortana extension (app, experience, plugin, etc..) that will receive a query from the user and based on this query construct an webpage URL and open that URL in the default client browser. My question is, can an App do that? Could you share any code example? Can this app run both on cell phones and windows laptops/desktops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
    string uriToLaunch = @"http://www.bing.com/";
    var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe so. You can create an app that implements  `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService` `IBackgroundTask` cortana will activate your background service if you register a VCD file with the right 'ListenFor' commands. You wire your app via `"VoiceCommandService Target="`.

Your background app would then launch the default browser.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185608.aspx) is a step by step guide.

Comment: I did not see the part of opening a web browser page there.. could you be more specific

Comment: I see your LaunchUriAsync below. You are saying that does not work?